# Better way of creating a PHP future date

Tags: php, date, mktime

Is there a quicker way of creating a date such as:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+3,   date("Y")));
```

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look into [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). I'd imagine your final code would look something like this:

```
$currentDate      = strtotime('today');//your date variable goes here
$futureDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 2 days', $currentDate));
echo $futureDate;
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11f89d0bd40240367a7d67f39e203c3cdfe028ad)

If you are using PHP version >= 5.2 I strongly suggest you use the new DateTime object. For example like below:

```
$futureDate = new DateTime("today");
$futureDate->modify("+2 days");
echo $futureDate->format("Y-m-d");
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/734937)